# Expressions for the multivariable function

Tags: functions

How to find expressions for f<sub>xx</sub> and f<sub>yy</sub> for the multivariable function f(x,y) = ln(x<sup>2</sup>y) + y<sup>3</sup>x<sup>2</sup>?

Comment: Maybe by chain rule?

Comment: I am not sure but any rule is okay. Aut yes, this chapter includes chain rule as well.

Comment: Can you please say me the procedure? It will be a great help for me

Comment: Should i do partial fraction twice with respect to x for fxx and same for y? I am not sure but I am guessing this...

Comment: Yes, I know partial differentiation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128204/discussion-between-zkutch-and-hadiuzzaman).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$f(x,y)= ln(x^{2}y)+y^{3}x$.

For finding $f_{x}$, we have to differentiate $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ as follows:

$ f_{x}= \frac{2xy}{x^{2}y}+ y^{3}.$

Now, for finding $f_{xx}$, differentiate $f_{x}$ with respect to $x$.

Try in the same way for $f_{yy}$.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful because it shows the way. Anyway, there is a ^2 after x at last.